# Simple Java program not printing anything

Tags: java, output

This is my first time posting here so please excuse any mistakes. I am an absolute beginner at Java, and I have the task of programming the 'Birthday problem.' It goes as follows:

Suppose that people enter a room one at a time. How people must enter until two share a birthday?
Write a program `Birthday.java` that takes two integer command-line arguments `n` and trials and performs the following experiment, trials times:

Choose a birthday for the next person, uniformly at random between `0` and `n−1`.
Have that person enter the room.
If that person shares a birthday with someone else in the room, stop; otherwise repeat.
In each experiment, count the number of people that enter the room. Print a table that summarizes the results (the count `i`, the number of times that exactly `i` people enter the room, and the fraction of times that `i` or fewer people enter the room) for each possible value of `i` from `1` until the fraction reaches (or exceeds) 50%.

The problem is, my code is not printing anything. It's compiling normally and not showing any errors, but when I try to run it it just doesn't show any output and I've run out of ideas as to what to do to improve it. An example of command-line arguments and how the output is supposed to look: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/codks.png)

Here is my code:

```java
public class Birthday {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        boolean[] birthdays = new boolean[n];
        int[] visits = new int[n + 2];
        int cumsum = 0;
        int k = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= trials; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                birthdays[j] = false;
            }
            for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
                int r = (int)(Math.random() * (n - 1));

                if (birthdays[r] == false) {
                    birthdays[r] = true;
                    continue;
                } else
                if (birthdays[r] == true) {
                    visits[k]++;
                    cumsum += visits[k];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        int l = 1;

        while ((double)(cumsum / trials) <= 0.5) {
            System.out.print(l + "(\t)" + visits[k] + "(\t)" + ((double) cumsum / trials));
            l++;
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: ``cumsum / trials`` uses integer division. Assuming that cumsum is less than trials, then the division will be zero. You would have to move the cast inside the parentheses. ``(double)cumsum / trials`` in order to get floating point division.

Comment: @NomadMaker thank you! However, shouldn't the code still print something even if the division is 0? I'm still not getting any output..

Comment: Probably, but it's 5am and I'm not willing to use a debugger at this time (too sleepy). Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: May I suggest that rather than reading from args[], that you assign the two variables in main(). That way, somebody who compiles and runs your program won't just crash because I don't know what values to put in.

Comment: What is your input? how can we reproduce this? I'm not sure I understand *How people must enter until two share a birthday?*; also, I think that whole text is a bit vague and problem is not clear.. better to narrow your question down to the specific, programming-related concept, rather than asking for solving the entire problem; meaning - try to debug it and see what goes wrong. `System.out.println(..);` some things, if you're not familiar with debugging.. As a side-note: your program can print something, **only** when the `while` evaluates to true, at least once, and its body is executed.

Comment: @NomadMaker thank you for your suggestions! I have never run a debugger before as all the assignments so far have been fairly simple. I'll try that and edit the post accordingly.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri thank you! Any help is much appreciated as this is my second week of programming. I attached an image of an example of my input (e.g. 365 10000), and I think the instructors missed the word 'many' in that sentence. I will try to debug and form my question more specifically. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since the statements you expect to see now but do not get them are all within your while loop you should focus your thoughts on how/when the while loop executes. Which essentially means to look at the condition, as others already suggested.

Just to check whether your code is able to print you can add a print statement where it would run unconditionally. For example at program start, or before the while loop is entered.

To focus on the condition it might be interesting to see the variable values used to decide the loop, so I'd add print statements before and inside the loop anyway. If you do this properly you won't even need to debug your code.

Last and not least, learning how to debug code in small projects will definitely help you with big ones.